# Does this j-box follow NEC electrical code?

Tags: junction-box, nec

I'm considering buying the following product for a security floodlight install:
[Arlington 8141-1 Vertical Siding Lamp Mounting Kit with Built-in Box for 1/2 Inch Vertical Siding LAP](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002W6ZOCO).  It seems to get great reviews, but I don't understand how this can possibly follow code.  It features a round, 4in diameter x **.5in deep** j-box.  In the simplest case, it would require six wires to connect a fixture at the end of the cable run (three from the NM cable, three from the fixture).  However, six 14-gauge wires would require a 4in round j-box that is **1.25in deep** according to NEC.

Can someone please explain to me why this j-box is acceptable or not?  Full disclaimer, I'm a total noob at electrical so it's entirely possible I'm just not understanding something properly.  Thanks!

Comment: Whatever canopied lamp you (should) buy will not have 14AWG wire, it will be 16 or less and not count, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ecmag.com](http://www.ecmag.com/section/codes-standards/box-fill-calculations-part-iv)'s interpretation of 314.16(B)(1) Conductor Fill:

> There is an exception under the conductor-fill provision that pertains to luminaire (fixture) conductors. An equipment-grounding conductor or four or fewer luminaire (fixture) wires smaller than 14 AWG, or both, entering a box from a domed luminaire (fixture) or similar canopy and terminating within that box, **can be omitted from box-fill calculations**. Under certain conditions, up to four luminaire (fixture) conductors and one equipment-grounding conductor can be installed but not counted in the box-fill calculation. The conductors must be 16 AWG or smaller and must enter the box from a domed luminaire (fixture) or similar canopy.

I always wondered why the wires on lights are so flimsy; that's why, so you don't have to count them in box fills.

Comment: Thanks!!  So based on the rule you presented, only the three wires from the power source would be counted.  Seems like there would be *just enough* room for them.  Is it fair to say that this product is only intended for use at the end of a cable run (ie. I shouldn't connect something else downstream from the fixture, solely using this j-box)?

Comment: 16 Awg is the smallest allowed by code for UL approved light fixtures.

Comment: @Ken - Correct. Pancake boxes are maxed-out with a single cable.